# AppendText is not a member System.Windows.Forms.Buttons

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub txtreciptappend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtrecipt.Click

    txtrecipt.Text = ""
    txtrecipt.appendtext("" + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("===========================Online Activation Pay Slip=========================" + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("==============================================================================" + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("" + vbNewLine)

    txtrecipt.Appendtext("" + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("Employee Name: " + vbTab & NameTextBox.Text + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab & EmployerTextBox.Text + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("Address: " + vbTab & AddressTextBox.Text + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("ID: " + vbTab & IDTextBox.Text + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext(vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab & "PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL" + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext(" " & vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("Employer Name: " + vbTab & EmployerTextBox.Text + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab & "PayDate" + vbTab + vbTab & Pay_DateDateTimePicker.Text + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("Employee Name: " + vbTab & NameTextBox1.Text)

    txtrecipt.Appendtext("==============================================================================" + vbNewLine)

    txtrecipt.Appendtext(" " & vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("Basic Salary: " + vbTab & Basic_SalaryTextBox.Text + vbTab & "Absent: " + vbTab & AbsentTextBox.Text + vbTab & "Late: " + LateTextBox.Text + vbTab & "Short Leave: " + Short_LeaveTextBox.Text + vbTab & "Half Day: " + Half_DayTextBox.Text + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext(" " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("Payment: " + vbTab + vbTab & PaymentTextBox.Text + vbTab & "Deductions: " + vbTab & DeductionTextBox.Text + vbTab & "Net Pay: " + vbTab & netpay.Text + vbNewLine)

    txtrecipt.Appendtext("==============================================================================" + vbNewLine)

    txtrecipt.Appendtext(" " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext(Today & vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab & TimeOfDay + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("==============================================================================" + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("                         WITH THANK'S FROM INTERSCAN                          " + vbNewLine)
    txtrecipt.Appendtext("==============================================================================" + vbNewLine)
```

I'm receiving error in txtrecipt.Appendtext.

Comment: why have you tagged this with `C#`?

Comment: Based on the name `txtrecipt` and the fact that you are calling `AppendText`, it appears that you think that you are working with a `TextBox` but the error message suggests (states outright, in fact) that you are using a `Button`.  The issue is obvious.  If you want to use a `TextBox` then use a `Textbox` and if you're using a `Button` then why are you displaying all that text to begin with?

Comment: By the way, the word is "receipt", not "recipt".

Comment: Even if you are using a `TextBox` though, it's silly to keep calling `AppendText` like that because there's an overhead involved.  Create the entire text in code first, then set the `Text` or the `Lines` property in one call.

Comment: You really ought to learn to use string interpolation and/or the `String.Format` method and similar too.  It will make code far more readable.

Comment: Finally, why do you keep swapping between `&` and `+`, even within the same line?  If you want to perform string concatenation then use the concatenation operator, i.e. `&`, only.

Comment: Look up the StringBuilder class.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `txtrecipt.appendtext` is wrong

make txtrecipt as `StringBuilder`

example:

```
StringBuilder txtrecipt = new StringBuilder ();
```

Then change `appendtext` to `AppendLine("your string")`